# Treating the question mark as an integer

Tags: java

Thank you so much for helping me.

So, I describe the problem more broadly so that I also have advice.

I am creating a very simple program in java that I calculate the unknown of x inside a proportion defined by the user in consoles. I ask the user through the Scanner class, the insertion of 4 numbers,One of these will obviously be the unknown to calculate.
The user will have to specify it when entering through a question mark, that’s the intention.
Now, I know that the code of a proportion is trivial, as fast as it is simple but I am deliberately complicating my life to face the study of methods and having no ideas I targeted the calculation of a proportion managed (unnecessarily) more complex (unnecessary).

So I ask you, how can I read in console input both numbers and characters So I ask you, how can I read in console input both numbers and characters?

Once read both (with very basic code no advanced library)I have to do the casting from ascii to int? Thank you very much hope I was clear.

Sorry for my english but I speak it a little bit.

Answer (score 2):

Read from your scanner as a `String`:

```
String input = scanner.nextLine();
```

Compare `input` to `?`:

```
boolean isQuestionMark = input.equals("?");
```

Then decide what you want to do based on that:

```
if (isQuestionMark) {
  // Do something for an unknown value.
} else {
  // Treat it as a number:
  double doubleValue = Double.parseDouble(input);
  // or int intValue = Integer.parseInt(input);
  // or whatever.
}
```